# Creating React Element Dynamically in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create an element in React with Typescript based on the tagName passed as props, and I want to add relative element props based on that tagName. Here is my code.

```
type ElementProps<Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements> =
  JSX.IntrinsicElements[Tag];

type Props = {
  tagName?: React.ComponentType | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
};

const Editable: React.FC<Props> = ({
  tagName = 'div',
  ...props
}) => {
  const htmlEl = useRef(null);

  const elementProps: ElementProps<typeof tagName> = {
    ...props,
    ref: htmlEl,
  };

  return createElement(tagName, elementProps, children);
};
```

I'm getting this error

```
Type 'keyof IntrinsicElements | ComponentType<{}>' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof IntrinsicElements'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>' is not assignable to type 'keyof IntrinsicElements'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>' is not assignable to type '"view"'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close.

`ElementProps` expects a string - `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements` whether  `typeof tagName` might be a `ComponentType<{}`.

Al you need to do is to move type restriction inside a type util.

```js
import React, { useRef, createElement } from "react";

type ElementProps<Tag> =
  Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[Tag]
  : never

type Props = {
  tagName?: React.ComponentType | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
};

const Editable: React.FC<Props> = ({
  tagName = 'div',
  ...props
}) => {
  const htmlEl = useRef(null);

  const elementProps: ElementProps<typeof tagName> = {
    ...props,
    ref: htmlEl,
  };

  return createElement(tagName, elementProps);
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZpSoxICiANkiEgHbwC%20cpUEIcARFXQx%20AbgBQ4mAE8wSOAyasYABR5hCAHgAqKAOYA%20OAF5xcOLr1wkADxosAJoTgBrJNIik4AKQDKADQA6AEk2KGAWQmA0RWY2QjM4AH4fAJCwiKiYxjiYQgBtSwBdRIAuOBYkADckKEkZOTg1CA0TXESYfQA5FGYk8uRhQIBhXkhKtm1ZeQAfV3dPVKDQmHDI6NjlQgl2CXE0CEj4WgdgToAjRgHUDECAMWHNZo0jYzgAChwO7t75N4ByU5Vf6YRKBcFgdQJdgAShMRi%205gORzgAAsYCB6Aw2kQSEhSO8WPh6PQYXskYdCPAkDllM9COVNmx6ZoGkhFp09D1mK92uZzODApCWoRQfy4FRSOV0ZiGGK4LtJOYqDB8FAWHBKNQ6LS2O9OdykNgaUpmVCyeJdkA)

> I was wondering if I could get the only detailed props regarding the tag that passed in the tagname?

Sure, it is possible.

```js
import React, { useRef, createElement } from "react";

type ElementProps<Tag> = Tag extends keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
  ? JSX.IntrinsicElements[Tag]
  : never;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type ObtainHTMLProps<T extends Values<JSX.IntrinsicElements>> =
  T extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<infer Props, HTMLElement> ? Props : never;

type AllowedProps = Values<{
  [Tag in keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]: {
    tagName: Tag;
  } & ObtainHTMLProps<JSX.IntrinsicElements[Tag]>;
}>;  

const Editable: React.FC<AllowedProps> = ({ tagName = "div", ...props }) => {
  const htmlEl = useRef(null);

  const elementProps: ElementProps<typeof tagName> = {
    ...props,
    ref: htmlEl,
  };

  return createElement(tagName, elementProps);
};

const canvas = <Editable tagName="canvas" width={20} /> // ok
const anchor = <Editable tagName="a" href={'www.example.com'} /> // ok

const invalid = <Editable tagName="canvas" href={'www.example.com'} /> // expected error
```

See react types `node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts`. You will find there  `IntrinsicElements`

[image]

Having `tagName` you can easily infer first argument of `DetailedHTMLProps`. See `ObtainHTMLProps`.

Now, you need to create a union of all allowed attributes and it is a finite number of props. See `AllowedProps`.

Comment: It works Thanks, I was wondering if I could get the only detailed props regarding the tag that passed in the tagname?

Comment: Thanks appreciate it. 